# PC works fine on Windows safe mode, but I can't format using Windows installation CD

Tags: windows, cpu, reboot

I have a laptop that restarts when booting Windows (not showing any errors, or any blue screens),  when tested in safe mode it starts without any problems. I thought then that the windows installation was corrupted so I've put the Windows installation CD but even so it restarts without any error or blue screen. It loads all the installation files, but once you get to start the "Windows" (the Windows installer) restarts. I'm doing some tests with the Ultimate Boot CD and the graphics card, ram, hard drive appear to be OK, the problem is when I try to stress test the CPU. So when I do the CPU stress test the laptop restarts almost immediately.

I thought it was the temperature of the CPU, but the CPU does not even have time to warm up. On Windows 7 Safe Mode I tried to use several programs to give me the temperature of the CPU, but none of them could show me the temperature, I only get null, void or "NA" on temperature field. Any tips?

aspire 7736zg
Model MS2279

Comment: Could be a dead hard drive but it could also be many things... I don't know why you've had a downvote so +1

Comment: What's the make and model of the PC? Can you run memtest86+ from a CD/USB? Newer Memtest versions will show CPU temperatures. A faulty contact between the CPU and the cooler can cause it to overheat in fractions of a second, it does not require time to "warm up"

Comment: I would run in safe mode and BACK UP first. Then, run a SMART tool, do other diagnostic things such as the temperature checks etc. I would run MSCONFIG and remove as much as you can from starting (research it first)

Comment: Im running Memtest86+ 5.01, no temperature stats there :/  ive added aspire 7736zg Model MS2279 to the post

Comment: [Try a clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135)

Comment: I would like to make a fresh installation, so thats not an option

Answer (score 1):

You may find the CPU temperature in the health / energy settings of your BIOS. There must be some information.

To be sure that there is really no blue screen - check the regkey for automatical restart on error: http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/229/ and set it to 0 (If you can boot into your windows in save-mode, you are able to set it).

For cleaning up your harddisk you can boot a small ISO like gparted-live http://gparted.org/download.php and then retry the installation from the windows CD. Be carefull with gparted to not delete the recovery partition of your Acer (if there is any).

Comment: There is no info related to CPU temperature on the BIOS. I've already disable automatical restart on Control Panel -> System -> Startup/Shutdown -> Automatically Reboot' - Memtest86 gives me no errors

Comment: I think the notebook is out of warranty? So you can open the back and check the CPU/GPU cooler is working fine (maybe clean it). Another "debug" option would be to replace the harddisk or remove one of the RAM-bars (if there are two available). Are you running it from DC or Battery? Maybe the Battery is broken and causes the reboot - so remove it and retry the installation.

Comment: Nope, still the same. Im going to send to some tech support. Thanks anyway guys.